# GWT Super Dev Mode - start without precompile

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-compiler, gwt-hosted-mode

In GWT 2.5.1 release notes there is a new option (-noprecompile) that can be added when starting super dev mode. But when i add it to the run configuration, i get the message

```
Unknown argument: -noprecompile
Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you using `-compiletest` at the same time?

Comment: Are you sure you use `gwt-codeserver.jar` from 2.5.1? The version printed comes from `gwt-dev.jar`, so if you mix JARs from different versions, you can have the output you describe.

Comment: I believe I forgot to copy the new .jar when switched to the new GWT in Eclipse. Thx.